# How to merge two dataframe horizontally and arrange the columns according to our own preference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframe horizontally based on rank column also rearrange these columns according to our own preference

This is my first dataframe

```
df_pa       
Rank    Name_pa    Country_pa
1       A          US
2       B          US
3       C          UK
4       D          MA
5       E          AU
```

And  this is my second dataframe

```
df_ca       
Rank    Name_ca    Country_ca
1       F          CA
2       G          PA
3       H          US
4       I          BR
5       J          CH
```

Can anyone please tell me how can we merge that two dataframe
horizontally based on rank column also place these column according to
our own preference

**This is my expectation.**

```
df              
Country_ca    Name_ca    Rank    Name_pa    Country_pa
CA            F          1       A          US
PA            G          2       B          US
US            H          3       C          UK
BR            I          4       D          MA
CH            J          5       E          AU
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Swap order of all columns by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_ca.iloc[:, ::-1].merge(df_pa, on='Rank')
```

Or use custom ordering by list:

```
df_ca[['Country_ca','Name_ca','Rank']].merge(df_pa, on='Rank')
```